# Change column order (different number of columns)

Tags: bash, awk

Original file looks like this:

```
stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615 on_2=ON-14-6003 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615 on_2=ON-14-6003 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615 on_2=ON-14-6003 spd=307 i_pow=150
```

And I need it to be like this:

```
stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
```

Simply said: if on_2 exists in a row, it should be the last value in a row. 
Order of the remaining values should stay the same.

If exists, on_2 is always 6th field - after *ind* and before *spd*. All fields have the same position in each row.

I guess that awk can make this happen, but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Did you try anything at all? assuming you had the knowledge that `awk` can make this happen?

Comment: @EdMorton just to put on_2 to be the last value/column if it exists and retain the same order of others.

Comment: [edit] your question to state that and any other so far unstated requirements including whether or not the "on_2" field always occurs in the same spot (and if it doesn't then update your example).

Comment: `on_2 field always occurs in the same spot - after ind and before spd` OK and do ind and spd always occur in the same locations? I'm trying to get you to simply tell us if on_2 is always the 6th field or if we have to search for `ind` and then `on_2` will be after that, wherever it occurs on the line.

Comment: Yes, if exists, on_2 is always 6th field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '$6 ~ /^on_2=/{$(NF+1)=$6; $6=""; $0=$0; $1=$1}1' file
stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
```

wrt why `$0=$0; $1=$1` is necessary for formatting:

`$6=""` changes `foo<blank>$6<blank>bar` to `foo<blank><blank>bar`, i.e. it leaves the blank before and after where $6 is now null and the number of fields is unchanged and $5 is still `foo` and $7 is still `bar`.

Then using `$0=$0` causes awk to re-split `$0` into fields and so the multiple blanks between foo and bar get treated as a single fied separator and so though $5 is still foo, now $6 is bar and there's 1 less field on the line. $0 still contains 2 blanks between foo and bar though as this didn't change $0, it just changed how it was split into the individual field assignments.

So then using `$1=$1` (or assigning to any field) causes awk to recompile $6 using the OFS value (a blank char) between fields so after this there's only 1 blank between foo and bar instead of 2.

So $0=$0 creates new values for $1->$NF and $1=$1 causes all FS between them to be replaced by OFS.

Comment: could you please add why `$0=$0; $1=$1` fixed the alignment, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

so you want to move column $6 at the end whenever matches.

```
awk '$6 ~ /^on_2/ { t=$6; $6=$7; $7=$8; $8=t } 1' file
```

---

in case matching pattern could exist in any column and we want to print it always at the end.

```
awk '{ 
    for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++)
        if($i~/^on_2/) {
            t=$i;
            for(j=i;j<NF;j++)
                $j=$(j+1);
            $NF=t
        }
    } 1' file
```

We could omit this shift by setting `t=$i; $i=""` and printing `$0 t`but then an extra FS is printed at the position of the moved column, breaking the alignment.

---

**update:** for how to use `$(NF+1)=i; $i=""` and preserve the alignment, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47142622/7589636).

Comment: does not provide OP's desired output.

Comment: @glenn jackman thanks, actually it was not a swap that OP asks for. I updated the answer doing a shift, so that works, although it seems not very efficient now.

Answer (score 2):

> Simply said: if on_2 exists in a row, it should be the last value in a
>   row. Order of the remaining values should stay the same.

Some more way to get desired output, doesn't matter where on_2 exists, search , extract, nullify and make it as last column :

```
$ awk 'match($0,/on_2=[^ ]* /){s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(s,"");$0=$0 FS s}1' infile
stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003 
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003 
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk 'match($0,/on_2=[^ ]* /){                # Search

         s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);        # if found extract it

         sub(s,"");                          # remove extracted part from row

         $0=$0 FS s                          # set extracted part at the end 

     }1                                      # print line/record
     ' infile
```

- `match($0,/on_2=[^ ]* /)` - search for regexp (`on2=[^ ]*`) in record/line/row

  `/on_2=[^ ]* /`

  - `on_2=` matches the characters `on_2=` literally (case sensitive)
  - Match a single character not present in the list below `[^ ]*`
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - matches the character  literally (case sensitive)
- `s=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);` if matched then extract string from record, and save it in variable `s`
- `sub(s,"")` - search for string in s, in record/line, substitute with null
- `$0=$0 FS s` - modify record/line/row
- `}1` - `1` at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, `print $0`. To know how awk works try, `awk '1' infile`, which will print all records/lines, whereas `awk '0' infile` prints nothing. Any number other than zero is *true*, which triggers the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(GNU `sed`).

```
sed -r 's/( on_2=[^ ]+)(.*)/\2\1/'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615  spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615  spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615  spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
```

If you want the output as tab space delimited.

```
sed -r 's/( on_2=[^ ]+)(.*)/\2\1/' Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: sed doesn't have to match the prefix prior to `on_2`. it shrinks the code a bit.

Comment: Good idea, but `[^(on_2)]` does not do what you think it does: it does not matches "not 'on_2'" -- it matches any character that is not `(` or `o` or `n` or `_` or `2` or `)`. You want `sed -r 's/( on_2=[^ ]+)(.*)/\2\1/' file`

Comment: `-r` is gnu only, use `-E` instead as that works in gnu and osx seds.

Answer (score 1):

another `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/(\son_2=\S+)(.*)/\2\1/' file

stat.sn 15094 291 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 361 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 360 usf=630 ind=32658 spd=307 i_pow=150
stat.sn 15094 272 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
stat.sn 15094 276 usf=630 ind=32615 spd=307 i_pow=150 on_2=ON-14-6003
```

Comment: `-r` is gnu only, use `-E` instead as that works in gnu and osx seds.